# What is the resultant force acting upward on the point of contact under an elastic deformation?

Tags: potential-energy, free-body-diagram, string, elasticity

The situation here is you have an elastic string (or a rubber band) fixed at two ends A and B.

```
A•-------------------------------------------------•B
```

An object is falling down from above and exactly collides with the string on the point C, which in the meantime leads to elastic deformation, as shown below.

```
A•    D•              •B
  \    |            /
   \   |        /
    \  |     /
      . . .
      C•
```

At the moment, we know the vertical components are not canceled. The object would, otherwise, stay there instead of rebounding upwards. The upward force component is greater than the downward force component, which is why the object would rebound after the collision.

**Here comes my question. What are the components of the upward force component?**

What I was thinking is there was a vertical component of force from the left-hand side string tension and a vertical component of force from the right-hand side string tension. In addition to these two components, I thought there was also a restoring force due to elastic deformation (assume there's no energy loss). If so, there would be another force calculated using

Hooke's Law: $$F = -k \cdot \Delta x$$

where $k$ is the spring constant and $\Delta x$ is the distance between line AB and the point C which is the normal segment, say CD, from point C to line AB. If so, there would be actually three vertical components of force in the upward direction on point C,

$$F_{up} = \cos(a) F_1 + \cos(b) F_2 + (-k) \cdot CD$$

where $F_{up}$ is the total force acting on the point C upwards, $a$ is the angle between AC and CD, $b$ is the angle between CD and BC, $F_1$ is the left-hand side string tension, and $F_2$ is the right-hand side string tension.

I don't know if the equation derived is correct? Please leave words.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry for confusions. Distance between A and B is fixed. They never get closer.

Comment: Couple of questions. 1. Is the rubber band stretched or relaxed between A and B before impact? 2. Doesn't the object impact the rubber band at point D and not at point C? 3. Is the position at C the maximum vertical deflection of the rubber band? 4. What is the velocity (if any) of the object when it impacts the rubber band?

Comment: 1)The rubber band is stretched (below its elastic limit) before impact. And 2) Yes the object impacts at point D. 3) Point C is the maximum vertical deflection of the rubber band. 4) Can you just take it as v?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) next time.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Haha I’m new in using stack exchange. Will learn the tools! But could u help me with this problem?